# Confusion regarding exponent algebra problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How would I evaluate something like $\big((-x)^{2}\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Normally I would do it like this:

$=\big((-x)^{2}\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$=\big(x^{2}\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$=\big(x\big)^{\frac{2}{2}}$

$=(x)^{1}$

$=x$

But is it just as valid to do it in the following way?

$=\big((-x)^{2}\big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$=\big(-x\big)^{\frac{2}{2}}$

$=\big(-x\big)^{1}$

$=-x$

Comment: This is a reminder that $(x^{a})^b=x^{ab}$ is not necessarily always true.  It will be true when $x$ is positive, but when $x$ can be negative errors can happen.

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this

$$\big((-x)^{2}\big)^{\frac{1}{2}} = (x^2)^{1/2} =: |x|$$

Comment: Why is it that it must be the absolute value of $x$?

Comment: $|x|$ is *defined* as $(x^2)^{1/2}$.  But intuitively it's because $y^{1/2}$ only gives you the positive (nonnegative) square root and the positive square root of $x^2$ is the absolute value of $x$.

Comment: @TazwarSikder if you want $x^{1/2}$ to have a single unique solution and be a *well defined function* then you requires $x^{1/2}=\sqrt{x}\geq 0$ for all $x$.  Otherwise you need to specify which branch cut you are using or you allow it to be a "*multi-valued function*" which isn't technically a function at all where you say something like $4^{1/2}=\{-2,2\}$ and you can't distinguish between which of the two values to use.